# neo4j-jdbc driver minimal viable snippet, unsure how to resolve dependancies

Tags: java, database, jdbc, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm having issues getting the minimal viable snippet for the Neo4J-jdbc driver working. I'm using intelliJ idea with gradle. When I `import org.neo4j.jdbc.*;`, `DriverManager` cannot be resolved and there are multiple occurences of `Unhandled Exception: java.sql.SQLException`. When I `import java.sql.*`, there are more `java.sql.SQLException` errors. When I import both, there are multiple errors as the references are ambigious between the two libraries.

The minimal viable snippet in the official documentation is as follows:

```
// Connecting
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost", 'neo4j', password)) {

    // Querying
    String query = "MATCH (u:User)-[:FRIEND]-(f:User) WHERE u.name = {1} RETURN f.name, f.age";
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
        stmt.setString(1,"John");

        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.execute()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Friend: "+rs.getString("f.name")+" is "+rs.getInt("f.age"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-jdbc-bolt', version: '3.1.0'
    compile 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.3'
}
```

I'm really looking for a minimal implementation here, I'm just curious as to what I'm missing out on to get the minimal snippet working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `java.sql.*` and that's all.Yes you will have some `SQLException`, but you just have to handle them in a `catch` or by adding the exception in your method signature (like below).

There is one mistake on the snippet, the `stmt.execute()` returns a `boolean` and not a `ResultSet`, so you need to replace it by `stmt.executeQuery()`.

This is a complete/working example :

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCTest {

  public static void main() throws SQLException {

        // Connecting
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost", "neo4j", "admin")) {

            // Querying
            String query = "MATCH (u:User)-[:FRIEND]-(f:User) WHERE u.name = {1} RETURN f.name, f.age";
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
                stmt.setString(1,"John");

                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println("Friend: "+rs.getString("f.name")+" is "+rs.getInt("f.age"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```